# How can I import a CommonJS module that exports a single function from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

Given this CommonJS module:

```
// cjs.js
module.exports = () => console.log("hi");
```

What can I put in my .d.ts

```
// cjs.d.ts
export ????
```

So that I can do a star import like this from a TypeScript file and pick up the correct types:

```
// main.ts
import * as log from "./cjs"

log()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use export assignment, but you need to declare an intermediary `const` that will be typed as the function:

```
declare const def: () => void
export = def;
```